# My chart has a decreasing Y axis, needs to start at +3 and go up to -3

Tags: chart.js2

I tried reverse=true in the yAxes settings but that does not seem to make a difference.

It always assumes that the min < max in the ticks settings.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse=True` does not work in 2.x

I was able to say:

```
           yAxes: [
              {
                id: 'y1',
                type: 'category',
                display: true,
                labels: ['-3', '-1', '+1', '+3'],
                position: 'right',
              }
            ]
```

to explicitly set the labels in decreasing order. The values continue ro be specified in the original scale so the plot appears correctly.

I also had to override the tooltip callback so that it would show the correct value on hover.